# What is "_q" in the "ctx.query._q" for?

Tags: strapi

til today, I have never had the situation when `ctx.query._q === true` (in `find: async (ctx) => {...}`). Instead, I've always defined `ctx.query`, like:

I can already find almost everything I need. My question: what is `_q` for?

```
query = {
   col0: ctx.request.body.col0,
   col1: ctx.request.body.col1,
   col2: ctx.request.body.col2
   …
};
```

Can someone explain that to me? Maybe with an example?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the find controller function, the `ctx.query` represent the query params of your request.

For example https://localhost:1337/restaurants?_q=french

In your case `ctx.request.body` come from the data you send in a POST request.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)